# Laravel - controllers without routing

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie to laravel.
I created new controller - book.
This is my code -

```
class BookController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('book.index');
    }

    public function insert()
    {

        return View::make('book.insert');
    }

}
```

My routes.php -

```
Route::get('book/', 'BookController@index');
//Route::any('book/insert', array('uses' => 'BookController@insert'));
```

When i uncomment 2nd line, i can access insert page.
Is it possible to access pages without add them to routes.

Now it produce this error
[image]

Comment: your routes are the access points into your app, so yes you have to have routes defined in some way

Comment: your code __should__ work unless there are collisions occuring. post the whole routes file.

Answer (score 4):

You may read about [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Execute this on terminal:

```
php artisan make:controller BookController
```

This command will generate `BookController.php` in your `app/controllers` folder. Read the code for more information.

Define in your `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::resource('book', 'BookController');
```

Actions Handled By Resource Controller:

[image: Route table]

Answer (score 0):

Route filters provide a convenient way of limiting access to a given route, which is useful for creating areas of your site which require authentication. So it is better to use route.php as Laravel framework indicates.
you can add filters to there as well, [refer documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing)